# Show all documents in a view without a pager in XPages

Tags: view, xpages

Is it possible to create a view that shows all documents without having to go to the next page?  In other words, I was asked if it's possible to create the same type of view we use to in the Notes client where the users would scroll down to see more documents rather than having to go to the next page.

I'd appreciate any suggestions you may have.  Thanks!

Comment: Personally I've never been a fan of the "show all documents" approach. Why does it exist in Notes Client? Because it's the standard approach for the client. But when you have a large view and users have to wait for it to load, is it a popular user experience? For web, how often do you see that approach? Do you jump to a category and scroll though entries on Google matching that category? When looking for previous questions here, did you scroll? Searching / filtering to get a small result set, finding your document from that, acting and moving on - IMHO that is a better approach for the web.

Answer (score 1):

There's is an infinite scrolling component in the XPages mobile controls, but that was built for mobile UIs. Don't have much experience with that.

@teleman's solution will work for medium sized views, but has it downsides for larger views (because it loads all entries at once: that might cause performance issues).

An alternative to that would be to create your own solution/ component: find a JavaScript plugin for your favourite JavaScript framework and link it to the view's data using REST calls (e.g. using the Extension Libraries REST control). Note that the ExtLib REST controls will add a `Content-Range` header to the response that you can use to determine what set of data to fetch next (e.g. when the user scrolled to the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 0):

In the `viewPanel` set `rows="5000"`.  You can then add CSS styling to make the view container scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

The Extension Library has a ready made control for that: https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-9EFFBH

Comment: Thanks for the link but when I clicked on it, it tells me that the page cannot be displayed.

Comment: You might want to try again.  Just checked loads nicely. Is it eventually blocked in your network? Another approach to check: https://www.google.com.sg/amp/s/quintessens.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/infinite-scroll-and-prevent-multiple-event-fire/amp/

Answer (score 0):

I think Mark Leusink's solution is the best anyway, because loading the whole set of entries on a page at once is really a huge performance issue. However, if you still want to do it, set the `rows` property of your `<xp:viewPanel>` or `<xp:repeat>` or whatever to `2147483647`, or to `#{javascript:java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE}`, this is the upper bound of `int` data type that is used in underlying `UIDataIterator` methods.

For Mark's response, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225236/9165609) answer that shows a trick to gain the effect of infinite scroll, though I haven't tried it myself.